# Updating a "Table" in a different Class in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a python GUI that is Build up like that:

First of all i have a File with the Class "App", which creats the basic form of the GUI:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from Frame1 import Do_SomethingPart1
from Frame2 import Do_SomethingPart2
from Header import Measurments

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        # Initial setup
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use('clam') #best so far
        self.style.configure('TButton', borderwidth=1, focusthickness=3, focuscolor='none')
        self.geometry('400x400')
        self.title('Test')

        # create tab widget
        self.tab_control = ttk.Notebook(self, padding=10)
        # create application instace
        self.application = Measurments(None, None)
        self.tab1 = Do_SomethingPart1(self.tab_control, self.application)
        self.tab2 = Do_SomethingPart2(self.tab_control, self.application)
 

        self.tab_control.add(self.tab1, text ='Test1')
        self.tab_control.add(self.tab2, text ='Test2')
        self.tab_control.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")

    def on_closing(self):
        '''
        shutdown sequence
        '''
        self.tab1.set_closing_flag(True) #pylint: disable=no-member
        self.destroy()
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.on_closing)
    app.mainloop()
```

So far so good.
The 2 other Tabs(Frames) are build up like this:

```
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
from Frame2 import Do_SomethingPart2

class Do_SomethingPart1(ttk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, Application):

        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)       
        
        self.application = Application

        self.Button_Change = ttk.Button(self, text= 'START', command=self.SendDatatoTable)
        self.Button_Change.place(x=100, y=100)

    def SendDatatoTable(self):
        
        Data=[(1, 0.12312, 1.2124),(2, 0.12312, 1.2124),(3, 0.12312, 1.2124),(4, 0.12312, 1.2124)]
        Do_SomethingPart2(Data)

    def set_closing_flag(self, status):
        '''
        set closing flag to false or true
        '''
        self.closing_flag = status
```

```
from tkinter import END, ttk, messagebox

class Do_SomethingPart2(ttk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, Application):
        
        '''
        Definition __init__: Initialisiere Aufbau des TEC_Frames
         '''
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)       
        self.application = Application

        self.total_rows=4
        self.total_columns=3
        for i in range(self.total_rows):
            for j in range(self.total_columns):
                self.e = ttk.Entry(self, width=10, font=('Arial',10,'bold'))
                 
                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)


    def FillTable(self, ItemList):
        print(ItemList)
        self.total_rows=len(ItemList)
        self.total_columns=len(ItemList[0])
        for i in range(self.total_rows):
            for j in range(self.total_columns):
                self.e = ttk.Entry(self, width=20,font=('Arial',16,'bold'))
                 
                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.e.insert(END, ItemList[i][j])
```

Basically all i want to do is to Send a List with Data from the Class Do_SomethingPart1 to the Class Do_SomethingPart2, in which a Table-Looklike gets created.

However it just does not Work. The Error i get is: TypeError: Do_SomethingPart2.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Application'

Does anyone have a better idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you call `Do_SomethingPart2(data)` inside `SendDatatoTabe()` but `Do_SomethingPart2` expects two arguments `parent` and `Application`? Also it looks like `data` is not a suitable object for both arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to pass the Application when you create the `Do_SomethingPart2` object?

Something like this

```
Do_SomethingPart2(Data, self.application)
```